# Changing the start day of week from 'monday' to 'tuesday' in Php

Tags: php, date, calendar

Hi friends i need to get the week count .

for ex 1,2,3 .... 52 based on the current year .

In php week starts from Monday or Sunday by default

Is there anyway to set 'Tuesday' has default starting day .

my code is ...

```
echo "current week of 2012 this year is ..". $weekNumber = date("W");
```

output for exapmle 16 . whereas correct should be 15 .

because i need the week starting from tuesday not monday , can anyone tell me how to do it .

since there is very less documentation on it will help others in future if answer is found :)

your help and time will be appreciated . or please suggest me a way in comments then :)

Comment: i wanted to know what should i add to make tuesday default starting week day

Comment: Weeknumber is more complicated then just starting it on a different day?

Comment: Whether or not the week starts on a Sunday, Monday or Tuesday will not affect the week number as they're all in the same week?

Comment: Hi last night we had an answer by ramesh where did it go was it wrong.

Comment: @dale ya it does depend on monday it will be week 1 and has soon has tuesday it becomes week 2 . so it doesnt depend on the week but on the day :) , but i did get the answer i was looking for thanks everyone

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got my solution thanks to an answer from ramesh.

To change Tuesday as the start of the week, I did it by using:

```
echo "Week count : ".date("W", strtotime("- 1 day"));
```