# How to set the "first day of the week" to Thursday in PHP

Tags: php, function, date

I want to set the first day of the week to Thursday (not Sunday or Monday), because it's the company's cut-off date.

I already have a code to determine the current week number of a date but it starts in Sunday or Monday.

How to modify these to my preference?

```
function findweek($date) {
    $monthstart=date("N",strtotime(date("n/l/Y",strtotime($date))));
    $newdate=(date("j",strtotime($date))+$monthstart)/7;
    $ddate=floor($newdate);
    if($ddate != $date) {
        $ddate++;
    }
    return $ddate;
}
```

Comment: I am getting ur point.......... wat exactly you want to do

Comment: in our company the start of week count for payroll is thursday not sunday or monday so iwant to start the count of every week of every month is thursday.

Comment: @RaydenBlack see if this can help you http://codepad.org/tI0nMQPo you may need to adjust datetime format

Comment: I checked it but I don't if it will help because it only display the output thursday not to start the week count on every thursday. I will check if the link you given will add to the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the start day of week from 'monday' to 'tuesday' in Php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174745/changing-the-start-day-of-week-from-monday-to-tuesday-in-php)

Comment: @RaydenBlack, in question you mentioned that `but it starts in sunday or monday` so i code something where starts from `thursday,` see if you can add it to the function and get desired return

Comment: I saw from google search this kind of php function intlcalendar.setfirstdayofweek, how can i use this?

Comment: May I ask how exactly are you planning to use this "start of the week" setting? Is it do display a calendar? Do some internal calculations? Otherwise, if you want `date('N')` to return 1 for Thursday, you can just subtract 3 or 4 from it (depending on whether the week starts on Monday or Sunday).

Comment: I was ask to create an application that calculates the work hours of the employees that starts from Thursday and ends in Wednesday weekly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php says that as of PHP version 5.6.23, 7.0.8 "*Weeks always start on monday. Formerly, sunday would also be considered to start a week.*" That said, is your problem that the number of weeks returned might be incorrect depending on whether today falls on or before Thursday of the current week? Maybe try something like this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$week = intval($date->format('W'));
$day = intval($date->format('N'));
echo $day < 4 ? $week-1 : $week;
```

If subtracting 1 isn't the answer you could play around with addition/subtraction, comparing the result with the actual answer you know to be true until you get the right formula. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
function findweek($date, $type = "l") {
    $time = strtotime($date);
    return date($type, mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", $time) , date("d", $time)-date("d", $time)+1, date("Y", $time)));
}

echo findweek('2015-09-16');
```

Comment: The result that i want is to set the first day of the week of a month to thursday not to find the week.