# Change the week start day from Monday to Saturday

Tags: php, function, dayofweek, weekday

To display the number of weekday I use the following:

```
echo "Today's date is: " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";
echo "The weekday is: " . date("l") . "<br>";
echo "The number of the weekday is: " . date("N") . "<br>";
echo "The week number is:" . date("W");
```

When the day is a Monday the above returns "The number of the weekday is: 1". This is because the week starts on Monday by default. What I need is to change the week start day to Saturday. Then the above "The number of the weekday is: " will return 3 on Mondays and 1 on Saturdays. In this regard the week number in a given date will be affected accordingly.

I have found this code in [PHP DateTime() class, change first day of the week to Monday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128854/php-datetime-class-change-first-day-of-the-week-to-monday) intended to change first day of the week from Sunday to Monday

```
    class EuroDateTime extends DateTime {


    // Override "modify()"
      public function modify($string) {


      // Change the modifier string if needed
      if ( $this->format('N') == 1 ) { // It's Sunday and we're calculating a day using relative weeks
          $matches = array();
          $pattern = '/this week|next week|previous week|last week/i';
          if ( preg_match( $pattern, $string, $matches )) {
              $string = str_replace($matches[0], '-7 days '.$matches[0], $string);
          }
      }
      return parent::modify($string);

  }
```

but I have not succeeded in modifying it so to change the week start day to Saturday.

My acid test for what I need to accomplish is particularly the output of:

```
echo "The number of the weekday is: " . date("N") . "<br>";
```

Can anyone please suggest the modification needed or another code snippet which will turn the week start day to Saturday?

Comment: Have you used "$this->format('N') == 6" ?

Comment: @Dhananjay Kyada Yes, I have added the above code I found in stackoverflow in the functions.php and I tried what you suggested but still what I get printed from my test is 1 for Mondays

Comment: Go through https://www.php.net/manual/en/intlcalendar.setfirstdayofweek.php. It may help you.

Comment: @Dhananjay Kyada Thanks! Unfortunately it had no effect to my test.

Comment: IMHO - if you're performing any date related arithmetic in PHP, you really should use a library. It will save you an enormous amount of time and headaches. Currently, https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ is the defacto.

Comment: @waterloomatt The date related arithmetic is in a plugin whose author cannot provide help. He said that I need to change how php’s date function works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $date = "2020-10-17"; 
    $standardDate = array("Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri");
    $dayNameOfWeek = date("D", strtotime($date));
    $key = array_search($dayNameOfWeek, $standardDate);
    echo $date . ' is ' . $key. 'th Day of this week!';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but when add below your code the:

Comment: <?php
echo "Today's date is: " . date("Y/m/d");
echo "The weekday is: " . date("l");
echo "The number of the weekday is: " . date("N");
echo "The week number is:" . date("W");
?>

Comment: I get altogether:
2020-10-17 is 0th Day of this week!
Today's date is: 2020/10/28
The weekday is: Wednesday
The number of the weekday is: 3
The week number is:44

Comment: But what I need is to have Wednesday taking the weekday number 4

Comment: yes because of $standardDate array for this purpose *start day from Monday to Saturday*

Comment: 0th Day of this week will be 0th of $standardDate array that will be *Sat* and if you want show first day with *1* you can add *+1* to $key and add empty array to $standardDate
and it will be:

Comment: .
.
    $standardDate = array("", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri");
.
.
.
    echo $date . ' is ' . ($key+1). 'th Day of this week!';

Comment: As it is now for php, the first day of the week is Monday. This is why if you just do echo date("N");  on a Monday it returns 1 (on a Sunday returns 7). I do not need to just show something. I want to make calendars, plugins, whatever code, to understand that the first day of the week is Saturday. If succeed then echo date("N"); will return 3 if current the day is Monday. Of course echo date("N"); will return 1  if current day is Saturday and it will return 2 if current day is Sunday.
I use echo date("N"); only to see if I have succeeded.

Comment: This link can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38642109/2489573

Comment: Thank you Masoud, but testing all suggestions in the above link with echo date("N"); still doesn't return 1 on Saturdays and 3 on Mondays.